# How can I remove days from dates?

Tags: string, date, format, stata

My Stata dataset looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJt78.png)

I would like to remove the days from this variable, as Stata cannot format this into dates
to use for my time-series.

Answer (score 2):

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen problem = "Tuesday. February 1, 2000"

. gen solution = subinstr(problem, word(problem, 1), "", .)

. l

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     |                   problem            solution |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. | Tuesday. February 1, 2000    February 1, 2000 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+

. gen wanted = daily(solution, "MDY")

. format wanted %td

. l

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |                   problem            solution      wanted |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | Tuesday. February 1, 2000    February 1, 2000   01feb2000 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```